# Image cut off with resizeMode cover

Tags: image, react-native

I have an image, when I want to make it bigger using resizeMode="cover", part of the image is cut off. How to fix that?

```typescript
render() {
    return (
```

```html
         <View style={styles.container}>       
            <Image
              style={styles.imgStyleGoogle}
              source={{uri: 'my.png'}}
            />
        <View>
    )
}
```

```typescript
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems:  'center',
        marginLeft: ratio * 5,
        marginRight: ratio * 5,
    },

imgStyleGoogle: {
        flex: 1,
        height: ratio*25,
        width: ratio*100,
        resizeMode:'cover',
    }
})
```

Here is example of the picture:
[image]

Comment: why not `resizeMode="contain"` ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was with `flex: 1` in Image, I deleted it from `imgStyleGoogle` and changed `resizeMode:'contain'`, and there is no more image cut off.

Comment: In my case, merely setting it to `resizeMode: "contain"` was enough.